# Shadow bind mount in fstab

Tags: systemd, fstab, bind-mount

I have a custom, non-default Ubuntu installation, where I use my other Linux distro's boot manager (rEFInd). As such, I don't want Ubuntu to see my EFI partition, on the principle that it has no business to what's there (which has already saved my ass last night when I did an `rm -rf /*`...). However, because I'm using btrfs as my file system, my `/boot` directory has to be in a UEFI-readable partition—like the EFI partition. So my solution to this conundrum is to shadow bind mount a subdirectory of the EFI partition, `esp:\EFI\ubuntu`, onto `/boot` through commands like these:

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /boot
mount --bind /boot/EFI/ubuntu /boot
```

This works perfectly. Ubuntu has access to a /boot partition that it can freely drop its vmlinuz and initramfs into and my boot manager automatically detects the installation. Booting and updating works as expected. The only caveat is, so far, that I needed to use the commands to mount /boot. So like any responsible sysadmin, I made an fstab entry:

```
UUID=XXXX-XXXX      /boot   vfat    rw,relatime 0 0
/boot/EFI/ubuntu    /boot   none    bind        0 0
```

Despite being analogous to the commands above, on boot the entire EFI partition remains mounted. The second line, performing the shadow bind mount, does not seem to execute. Is there a way to make this work in fstab and if not, what would be a reliable way to perform the bind mount as quickly as possible after the initial mount?

Comment: Does dmesg show the mounts executing. What happens when you do a mount -a?

Comment: What is the output of `mount`? I am wondering if it is a race condition.

Comment: Thanks @RamanSailopal, you helped me find an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RamanSailopal suggested, the answer was (of course) in dmesg. The root of the problem was that systemd creates unit files from fstab entries, and for whatever reason, they must have a filename that maps to the mountpoint. In other words, multiple mounts per mountpoint are disallowed.

I worked around this by creating a systemd service file that injects itself as a dependency of `local-fs.target`, by all means acting like a regular systemd mount unit:

`/etc/systemd/system/boot-shadow-mount.service`:

```
# Performs the shadow bind mount to hide the ESP at /boot
# and instead expose the ubuntu subdirectory.

[Unit]
Description=/boot shadow bind mount
Requires=boot.mount
Conflicts=umount.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/mount --bind /boot/EFI/ubuntu /boot
ExecStop=/bin/umount /boot
RemainAfterExit=True

[Install]
RequiredBy=local-fs.target unattended-upgrades.service
```